# How can I best animate a 2D sprite in Unity3d?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'd like to animate a 2D sprite in Unity3D. What's the best (least complex) method of doing this?

I have several images that I'd like to cycle through to create the animation. What is the simplest code and setup for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some scripts in the Unify Community wiki at [Animating Tiled texture](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Animating_Tiled_texture) in javascript and in C#. They are a good starting point. Otherwise you can use the enhanced solution [SpriteManager](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SpriteManager)